# Retrieving a large result set in MySQL without affecting speed

Tags: java, mysql, resultset, mib

In my application i have result set containing more than 20000 rows. I want to save it to an Array List. I am using the below code for this.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") ;
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Data",     "root", "root") ;
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement() ;
  String query = "select * from temp ;" ;
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query) ;

  ArrayList<String> varList = new ArrayList<String>();
  while(rs.next()){
  varList.add(rs.getString(1));
  }
```

When i use the query it takes more time to fetch the data from the resultset and too slow if the table contains more than 20000 entries. How can this be solved ? Any suggestions will be very greatful.

Comment: what is the structure of your table?

Comment: What are you doing with those 20,000 rows, anyway? Do you really need each and every one of them?

Comment: If you really need to do it that way, you should instantiate your list with a higher initial capacity, to avoid unnecessary copying of elements when adding lots of entries.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the table?  Do you really need all the rows?

Comment: What's the concrete functional requirement? What would you ultimately like to do with those 20,000 rows? Presenting it to the enduser in a single table? If so, why don't you make use of filtering and/or pagination like as Google does? Google is so fast because it doesn't load and display a gazillion of records at once. Instead, it loads and displays only 10 records at once based on given filter. You shouldn't expect that the enduser should wait ages for 20,000 records to load and then do a Ctrl+F to find the information it is looking for. This is extremely naive/primitive.

Comment: Yes. I want all the rows because it's networking application. The db contains the MIB(Management Information Base) variables

Comment: Why must the user have all of them?  Why not query as needed?  You realize that there's no optimization that will make this faster than a O(N) problem.

Comment: Threads can be used to Asynchronously Fetch records and then append together to form a Single Vector. Even for that there must be a Primary or Distinct Key. Preferably a NUMBER. 

Do a Select to get the COUNT(*) and based on the total rows divide and create multiple threads.

Comment: I want to populate all that MIB variables in to a JTable. I have already done that but the Jtable take more time to populate beacause the query is too slow.

Comment: 20,000 records in a JTable? This definitely needs some rethinking.

Comment: Are you saying you want a `JTable` with 20.000 rows? Try this: open a database viewer, load the rows there, and read all of them. After you're done, you'll probably think about a different approach...

Comment: Sorry it's 2000. Can i take 2000 rows? Can i implement pagenation on this!

Comment: You can take as many rows as you want. But don't you think 2.000 rows are still far too many? Have you ever looked at the first 200 pages of a Google search result??

Comment: You could narrow your search results by some criteria, or use a lazy loading list. You would populate the first few (20-50) rows and only add rows when the user actually scrolls down.

Comment: sinc you are using only one column don't use `SELECT *` specify the column name

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that you're trying to solve the wrong problem.  Whatever you're doing with those 20,000 rows, you should do it *at the database* and only return the results of the operation (which, hopefully, will take much less space) to the client.

If you told us exactly what you're trying to do with the data, we might be able to offer more specific suggestions on how to do that.

(Alternatively, if you really *do* need all the 20,000 rows at the client, you might want to skip the database entirely and just store them at the client.)

Answer (score 1):

20000 is not a big number in terms of database rows.

You problem could be in ArrayList.

By default, an ArrayList has a default size, I'm not sure how many, say 100. And when the inserted items are more than that number, Java will create a new arraylist with size incremented by some value, I'm not quite sure how many, say 100 also. Then the content in previous list will be copied to the new list. These are all string operations in your case. So you can see why it is slow. Do the following may solve your problem.

```
int rsSize = getResultSetSize(connection,query);  //return the size of the result set first
ArrayList<String> varList = new ArrayList<String>(rsSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue isn't the database, it's likely the catenation of items to the list.  You should provide java with more memory.  If it is the list.add then you could speed that up by allocating an array the size of the result and then using indexing to insert the data into the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do with those 20000 records after fetching it.? What ever you want to do see if you can do it at DB level using PL-SQL code. Many programmers don't use power of PL-SQL. Whatever you can do with other high level programming language, most of things among these can be done with PL-SQL too.